# Как лучше всего сохранять лог(java)

Tags: java, android

Возник такой вопрос, как работать с логом в Android. К примеру у меня есть приложение, оно обменивается данными с другим устройством. Как мне лучше всего реализовать возможность сохранения данных из этого обмена? Если учитывать, что данных может со временем накопиться много.
Я собираюсь просто записывать логи с данными в список, а после сохранять в файл. При этом я собираюсь учитывать два фактора:

1. Для каждого дня файл будет иметь разное имя(к примеру 24122019_serverlog.txt)
2. В файле не может быть более 100000 строк, иначе будет создан следующий файл с индексом "_x", где x - это номер файла.

Если у кого-нибудь есть опыт в этом деле буду рад услышать ваше мнение)

Comment: Лучше начните с изучения логера java/android обычно они позволяют тонко настраивать себя, например формат данных, куда выводить логи (консоль, файл, база данных, сеть, почта, ...), если выводить в файл, то возможность настройки для ограничения размера файла и создания нового и т.п.

Comment: @gil9red, хорошо) Тогда начну разбираться прямо сейчас)